# difference between judicial situation and legal situation

Tags: meaning

Is there a  difference between "judicial" situation and "legal" situation, or is it the same?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, *legal* refer to the laws governing a state, for instance. *Judicial* refers specifically to the administration of justice, based on those laws.

[Legal](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Legal):

> - Conforming to the law; required or permitted by law; not forbidden by law.

[Judicial](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/judicial):

> - Relating to the courts or belonging to the office of a judge; a term pertaining to the administration of justice, the courts, or a judge, as in judicial power.

[Brazil-U.S. Legal and Judicial Studies Program](http://www.wcl.american.edu/brazil/):

> - The Brazil-U.S. Legal and Judicial Studies Program at American University Washington College of Law is a comparative law program focused exclusively on Brazil and the United States and their respective *legal and judicial institutions*.

[Legal And Judicial Structure in Saudi Arabia](http://www.saudiembassy.net/about/country-information/government/legal_and_judicial_structure.aspx):

> - Since Saudi Arabia is an Islamic state, its judicial system is based on Islamic law (Shari’ah) for both criminal and civil cases. At the top of the legal system is the King, who acts as the final court of appeal and as a source of pardon.

Comment: May I say what an extraordinarily good answer this was. I assume you are a lawyer.